# Dominios en WebLogic: No se esperaba FILES en este momento

Tags: cmd, weblogic

Soy nuevo trabajando con *WebLogic* y acabo de instalar el servidor, pero al intentar ejecutar el archivo **config.cmd** me sale este mensaje:

> No se esperaba FILES en este momento

Este es el código del archivo **config.cmd**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR /f %%i in ('cd') do set MYPWD=%%i

SET SCRIPT_PATH=%~dp0
FOR %%i IN ("%SCRIPT_PATH%") DO SET SCRIPT_PATH=%%~fsi

@REM Set the ORACLE_HOME relative to this script...
FOR %%i IN ("%SCRIPT_PATH%\..\..") DO SET ORACLE_HOME=%%~fsi

@REM Set the MW_HOME relative to the ORACLE_HOME...
FOR %%i IN ("%ORACLE_HOME%\..") DO SET MW_HOME=%%~fsi

@REM Set the home directories...
CALL "%SCRIPT_PATH%\setHomeDirs.cmd"

@REM Set the config jvm args...
SET CONFIG_JVM_ARGS=%CONFIG_JVM_ARGS% -DCOMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME=%COMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME%

CALL "%SCRIPT_PATH%\commEnv.cmd"

FOR %%i IN ("%JAVA_HOME%") DO SET JAVA_HOME=%%~fsi

SET CLASSPATH=%FMWCONFIG_CLASSPATH%;%DERBY_CLASSPATH%

:PARSEARGS
SET VALIDATE=%2
FOR %%I IN (%VALIDATE%) DO SET VALIDATE=%%~I
if NOT {%1}=={} (
  IF "%1"=="-help" (
    SET ARGUMENTS=%1
    GOTO :RUN
  )
  IF "%VALIDATE:~0,1%"=="-" (
    ECHO ERROR! Missing equal^(=^) sign. Arguments must be -name=value!
    EXIT /B 1
  )
  IF "%VALIDATE%"=="" (
    ECHO ERROR! Missing value! Arguments must be -name=value!
    EXIT /B 1
  )
  GOTO :SETARG
) ELSE (
  GOTO :RUN
)

:SETARG
SET ARGNAME=%1
SET ARGVALUE=%2
SHIFT
SHIFT
FOR %%I IN (%ARGVALUE%) DO SET ARGVALUE=%%~I
IF /i "%ARGNAME%"=="-log" (
  IF "%ARGVALUE:~1,1%"==":" (
    SET ARGUMENTS=%ARGUMENTS% %ARGNAME%=%ARGVALUE% 
  ) ELSE (    
    SET ARGUMENTS=%ARGUMENTS% %ARGNAME%=%MYPWD%\%ARGVALUE%  
  )  
  GOTO :PARSEARGS
) ELSE (
  IF  /i "%ARGNAME%"=="-silent_script" (
    IF "%ARGVALUE:~1,1%"==":" (
        SET ARGUMENTS=%ARGUMENTS% %ARGNAME%=%ARGVALUE% 
    ) ELSE (    
        SET ARGUMENTS=%ARGUMENTS% %ARGNAME%=%MYPWD%\%ARGVALUE%  
    )  
    GOTO :PARSEARGS
  ) ELSE (
    IF /i "%ARGNAME%"=="-useXACML" (
        SET UTILS_MEM_ARGS=%UTILS_MEM_ARGS% -DuseXACML=%ARGVALUE%
    ) ELSE (
        SET ARGUMENTS=%ARGUMENTS% %ARGNAME%="%ARGVALUE%"
    )
    GOTO :PARSEARGS
  )
)
:RUN
PUSHD %COMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME%\common\lib

if exist %SCRIPT_PATH%\cam_config.cmd (
  call %SCRIPT_PATH%\cam_config.cmd
)


SET JVM_ARGS=-Dprod.props.file="%WL_HOME%\.product.properties" -Dpython.cachedir="%TEMP%\cachedir" %UTILS_MEM_ARGS% %COMMON_JVM_ARGS% %CONFIG_JVM_ARGS%

IF EXIST %JAVA_HOME% (
  IF "%ARGUMENTS%" == "" (
    %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw %JVM_ARGS% com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController %ARGUMENTS%
  ) ELSE (
    %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JVM_ARGS% -Djdbc=true com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController %ARGUMENTS%
  )
) ELSE (
  CALL :SET_RC 1
)

SET RETURN_CODE=%ERRORLEVEL%
POPD

IF DEFINED USE_CMD_EXIT (
  EXIT %RETURN_CODE%
) ELSE (
  EXIT /B %RETURN_CODE%
)

:SET_RC
EXIT /B %1
```

¿Es posible revolver esto?

Comment: Pon el contenido del archivo _cmd_.

Comment: ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

REM Determine the location of this script...
SET SCRIPTPATH=%~dp0
FOR %%i IN ("%SCRIPTPATH%") DO SET SCRIPTPATH=%%~fsi

REM Set the MW_HOME relative to this script
FOR %%i IN ("%SCRIPTPATH%\..\..\..") DO SET MW_HOME=%%~fsi

REM Delegate to the main script...
CALL "%MW_HOME%\oracle_common\common\bin\config.cmd" %*

ENDLOCAL

Comment: Entonces FILES debería estar en otra parte del código, no aparece en el cmd.

Comment: ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR /f %%i in ('cd') do set MYPWD=%%i

SET SCRIPT_PATH=%~dp0
FOR %%i IN ("%SCRIPT_PATH%") DO SET SCRIPT_PATH=%%~fsi

REM Set the ORACLE_HOME relative to this script...
FOR %%i IN ("%SCRIPT_PATH%\..\..") DO SET ORACLE_HOME=%%~fsi

REM Set the MW_HOME relative to the ORACLE_HOME...
FOR %%i IN ("%ORACLE_HOME%\..") DO SET MW_HOME=%%~fsi

REM Set the home directories...
CALL "%SCRIPT_PATH%\setHomeDirs.cmd"

REM Set the config jvm args...
SET CONFIG_JVM_ARGS=%CONFIG_JVM_ARGS% -DCOMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME=%COMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME%

CALL "%SCRIPT_PATH%\commEnv.cmd"

Comment: FOR %%i IN ("%JAVA_HOME%") DO SET JAVA_HOME=%%~fsi

SET CLASSPATH=%FMWCONFIG_CLASSPATH%;%DERBY_CLASSPATH%

:PARSEARGS
SET VALIDATE=%2
FOR %%I IN (%VALIDATE%) DO SET VALIDATE=%%~I
if NOT {%1}=={} (
  IF "%1"=="-help" (
    SET ARGUMENTS=%1
    GOTO :RUN
  )
  IF "%VALIDATE:~0,1%"=="-" (
    ECHO ERROR! Missing equal^(=^) sign. Arguments must be -name=value!
    EXIT /B 1
  )
  IF "%VALIDATE%"=="" (
    ECHO ERROR! Missing value! Arguments must be -name=value!
    EXIT /B 1
  )
  GOTO :SETARG
) ELSE (
  GOTO :RUN
)

Comment: Sigo sin ver FILES... Además te recomiendo poner esos códigos batch editando la pregunta y borrar los comentarios.

Comment: Prueba a comentar el `ECHO OFF` y así podrás ver qué orden es la que falla justo antes del error. Me da la impresión de que tiene que ver con algunas comillas que faltan y en alguna variable con valor `c:\Program Files` el espacio crea un problema de sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

Los problemas más comunes con weblogic suelen ser las variables de entorno. Al ser un windows, dichas variables estarán en propiedades del sistema ---> Variables de entorno. Espero que me perdoneis, soy usuario de UNIX/Linux.

Asegurate de tener:

La variable $JAVA_HOME={C:,D: .. etc}\Program Files\jdk.....
La variable WL_HOME={C:,D: .. etc}\rutaInstalacion\wlserver(numero)
La variable PATH debe contener al menos, la ruta a la carpeta lib de tu jdk.

Con estas dos variables bien indicadas, se suelen solventar muchos problemas de weblogic.

No recomiendo utilizar una jre de java. Utiliza mejor una jdk.

Comment: Estas son los valores de las variables. WL_HOME=C:\Users\Lenin\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver          JAVA_HoME=c:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_8. Y no se debe definir la variable ORACLE_HOME?

Comment: No sería necesario salvo que tengas instalado una BBDD de Oracle.

Comment: si intento ejecutar este archivo "setWLSEnv.cmd" me sale el mismo mensaje "No se esperaba Files en este momento". El archivo mencionado, es para crear el dominio de forma manual.

Comment: Como ya he comentado, no tengo mucha experiencia en entornos Windows.... pero me da a mi que puede ser un problema con las rutas de windows. Mi recomendación es la siguiente:
- Instala de nuevo Weblogic asegurandote que las rutas sean en raiz de la unidad donde la instales, es decir (por ejemplo), create una carpeta llamada oracle y dentro instala Weblogic y la jdk. Deberia quedar como c:\oracle\jdk1.x.x.x  y  c:\oracle\weblogic\middleware\.... Cambia las variables de entorno adecuando a la nueva instalacion.